# How can I write 32 std_logic_vetor words to an array in VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I need to write 32 std_logic_vetor-s to an array 
kind of like

`data_array <= {0x0000, 0xA0F1, 0xFFF1, 0xBFB1, 0x1F9A, 0x03CD,...}`

I have looked through some examples and everyone is doing it word-by-word.

Do I need a loop for that?

What if they are constants, do I have to write those dozens of strings?

Comment: It is possible two write 32 vectors at a time (see answer below) but it requires that all the destination locations can be written at once and thus they have to be *real hardware registers*. The reason why writing word-by-word is often done is because in RTL (synthesizable) code you then can use a memory to hold the data. A memory is **a lot** more efficient in area and power but you have access (in both read and write) to one, (maximum  two for DPR) elements at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
data_array <= (x"0000", x"A0F1", x"FFF1", x"BFB1", x"1F9A", x"03CD",...)
```

Whether you can use a for loop or not depends on how your std_logic_vectors are provided. If you take them from another array or a concatenated std_logic_vector, you can use a loop.

If they are constants, you have to define them somewhere, so yes, you have to write them down (or calculate them using a function, if that is appropriate).